# What does the following Stata code mean (x/max=.)?

Tags: stata

I do not know Stata and I need to know what the following code means. I understand that `prtvtacy` gets `recode`d to 1 if it is 1 and 0 else. But what does  `recode prtvtacy (66/max=.)` mean?

```
*cyprus
tab prtvtacy
tab prtvtacy, nolab
recode prtvtacy (66/max=.)
 
recode winlose 0=1 if prtvtacy==1
```

Comment: The `recode` you first discuss (the second in your code) is that `winlose` gets changed from 0 to 1 if `prtvtacy` is 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are inline comments for each line. Note that variable in Stata means what is most often called a column in many other programming languages.

```
*cyprus                            // <- This is a comment
tab prtvtacy                       // <- This shows the frequency of the variable prtvtacy
tab prtvtacy, nolab                // <- Same as above, but shows numeric code instead of label
recode prtvtacy (66/max=.)         // <- Any value in variable prtvtacy between 66 and the highest value is changed to missing value (.)
 
recode winlose 0=1 if prtvtacy==1  // <- Set variable winlose to 1 for observations where winlose is 0 and prtvtacy is 1
```